# A network related or instance specific error-26 while deploying MVC5 app to Windows server 2012 and Migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, iis, visual-studio-2017

Please don't mark it as duplicate tried out few of these similar errors already .

Scenario :

Just tried to deploy the MVC5 Entity Framework Code First Migration to a Windows 2012 Server which initially worked as without Styles/JS running so redeployed it changing the Bundling names ( this have no chance to be related with the current issue but stating it here). The CodeFirst DB gets created properly and the publish is successful but not able launch the app, it throws this error.

WebConfig Connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="ERPContext_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=TSSERVER;Initial Catalog=TS_ERP;User ID=tssql;Password=*******"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

TroubleShoot:

- Checked SQL Services are running ( also Sql Server Browse )
- Checked Connection String /Credentials( if its wrong the DB itself wont have created at first place by Migration
- Manually able to log into the SQlServerStudio using same credentials
- Was working fine in the initial deployment without any problem
- DB user instance has admin rights
- IIS configurations are defaults

Would that mean its related to any Firewall or Port ( 1433/1434) issues? But since the initial deployment was successful the Server/Network admin team has rejected that request to investigate.

Is there any chance that there are multiple references of connectionstrings for Entity Framework etc. I had check the IIS virtual directory connections too. 
The application deployed ( web server) and SQlServer runs on the same server machine so the SQL remote also doesn't seems to be the issue here.

Appreciate any thoughts regarding the  same.

Apologies for posting the full error stack just in case if it has more hints

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>    establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)[SqlException (0x80131904):    >System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +350
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +156
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +268
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +314
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +204
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +428
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) +572
>
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3>d__6.MoveNext() +292 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   +503    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.d__8.MoveNext() +924
>
> [EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.d__8.MoveNext() +1255 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__9.MoveNext()
>   +514    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__3d`1.MoveNext()
>   +312    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   +579    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +48    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext() +734 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +48    System.Data.Entity.Internal.d__0.MoveNext() +332    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.d__25`1.MoveNext()
>   +371    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +48    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__13.MoveNext() +438    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +48    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<RoleExistsAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +403    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1
>   func) +232    ERPLite.Startup.CreateRolesandUsers() in
>   C:\Users\trss\source\repos\ERP\ERP\Startup.cs:36
>   ERPLite.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in
>   C:\Users\trss\source\repos\ERP\ERP\Startup.cs:22
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +146    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +93
>   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder) +209
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1
>   startup) +842
>
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +51 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
>   +101    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
>   +136    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +162
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +583
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +396
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +333
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +124    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +700

Comment: The error clearly says that the server is not found. This means or it's not running, or you use incorrect server name, or it's firewall. Do you have named or default instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for those who encounter this error and already checked the list of troubleshooting points mentioned in the question.

Once creating a publish/deployment using WebDeploy it will add 1 more connection string in the target webconfig as _DatabasePublish (refer question) apart from the existing local connectionString.

I assumed that the _DatabasePublish would be used by the published app but it requires both the connectionStrings pointed to the same DB. 
While creating the EF Migration it used _DatabasePublish and subsequent ( Seeding etc) used the other connectionString. But I'm sure there should be ways to change this though.